# how to redirect after login to a particular page which depend upon the page from which login is clicked in magento?

Tags: magento

How to redirect after login to a particular page which depend upon the page from which the login is clicked in  magento? I know redirection haappens in `AccountController.php`. But how to get the link of page from where customer  logged in.I have two different pages for login .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy. All you have to do is insert next code somewhere on your pages from which you're making *Log In*.

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*'));
```

What it does - it sets the variable to **Customer** session, that holds url of the referrer page. `AccountController` will send you back on that page after logging in, if the variable is set.

### UPDATE

Just thought I may need to edit the post, since the info is not full. So as I've learned some time ago, there are actually 2 session keys that rule the logic of "returning back/redirecting" after logging in:

- `before_auth_url`: this should be set to the page, you want your user to see, if his login/password haven't passed the validation
- `after_auth_url`: this is url you want your user to be redirected to after successful log in

Now the solution above worked, because Magento automatically sets `after_auth_url` = `before_auth_url` if the former is not set.

**Here's the quick example**: you have login form on Checkout. So you want your users to be redirected back to Checkout after they've logged in. **BUT** you don't want your users to be redirected back to checkout if they failed to enter valid credentials. Rather than that you want them to stay on Login page, so they have ability to request Forget Password email or Register anew. Once they are able to login, you want them to be back at Checkout.

As complex as that use-case sounds, it's actually quiet simple to achieve, and is't already done in Magento Checkout. So here's what you need to set:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
    ->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*'));
```

That's all folks :)

Comment: This worked like a charm! I didn't expect to be so simple.Thank You.

Comment: where i have to use this

Comment: @Kothari Anywhere on the page where your login form is loaded. E.g. I used it in `template/tm/firecheckout/checkout/link.phtml`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this as well. I guess this is what you want.(MAGENTO 1.7)

Login to Magento Admin.

Goto System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Login Options.

In the dropdown there is option of where to redirect customer once they are logged in.

i.e. Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in or not.